# Using nested ng-Repeat to generate a HTML structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am migrating my HTML code to Angular using `ng-repeat`. The HTML structure is like currently i have 9 items and I am displaying the 3 items max per row. I may have any number of items and the rule is 3 items max per row. Currently my HTML looks like this -

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg">
       <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="1.05">Item 1</button>
       </div>
       <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="2.05">Item 2</button>
       </div>
       <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="2.55">Item 3</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="2.65">Item 4</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="3.05">Item 5</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="4.95">Item 6</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="4.15">Item 7</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="1.15">Item 8</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="1.95">Item 9</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the requirement is I want this same structure to be generated using Angular i.e. I will receive a JSON payload which will have Item Name & Price and my code should generate the same structure.

My JSON will look like this -

```
    items = [
     { name: "item1", price: "1.05" },
     { name: "item2", price: "2.05" },
     { name: "item3", price: "2.55" },
     { name: "item4", price: "2.65" },
     { name: "item5", price: "3.05" },
     { name: "item6", price: "4.95" },
     { name: "item7", price: "4.15" },
     { name: "item8", price: "1.15" },
     { name: "item9", price: "1.95" }
    ];
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7eYnt/ See if this helps.

Comment: your question is how to use ng-repeat?

Comment: Personaly I would just spit out a list, then use CSS to style it. In this case either float the list items, or give them `display:inline-block`, with a width of around 33%. That way when you want to have 4 per row, you only need to change that width to 25ish%. You also then open up the option of Media Queires to vary the number of items per row based on screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either restructure your JSON response, or process your JSON response before you pass it into the angular directive,
so that it looks like this:

```
var itemRows = [
 [{ name: "item1", price: "1.05" },
 { name: "item2", price: "2.05" },
 { name: "item3", price: "2.55" }],
 [{ name: "item4", price: "2.65" },
 { name: "item5", price: "3.05" },
 { name: "item6", price: "4.95" }],
 [{ name: "item7", price: "4.15" },
 { name: "item8", price: "1.15" },
 { name: "item9", price: "1.95" }]
];
```

.. and then pass `itemRows` (not items) as the object to be displayed in the template.

Assuming that changing the backend is not an option,
pre-processing is the way to go, here is one way:

In Javascript:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myItems',[]);

    myApp.controller('ItemRowsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var items = [
        { name: "item1", price: "1.05" },
        { name: "item2", price: "2.05" },
        { name: "item3", price: "2.55" },
        { name: "item4", price: "2.65" },
        { name: "item5", price: "3.05" },
        { name: "item6", price: "4.95" },
        { name: "item7", price: "4.15" },
        { name: "item8", price: "1.15" },
        { name: "item9", price: "1.95" }
      ];
      var itemRows = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            itemRows.push([]);
        }
        var itemRow = itemRows[itemRows.length - 1];
        itemRow.push(items[i]);
      };  
      $scope.itemRows = itemRows;
    }]);
```

In your template:

```
    <body ng-app="myItems">
      <div ng-controller="ItemRowsCtrl">
        <div class="row clearfix" ng-repeat="itemRow in itemRows">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg">
               <div class="btn-group" ng-repeat="item in itemRow">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="{{item.price}}">{{item.name}}</button>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

[JsBin answer](http://jsbin.com/juwes/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Even i was able to do it by changind the Backend JSON similar way you have shown. The only issue was i could not do that. Yeah the for loop in the controller helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce what your trying to ask in this http://jsfiddle.net/7eYnt/. Hope it helps. It explains the ng-repeat concept in your scenario.
Thanks.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row clearfix" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg">
   <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="1.05">{{ item.name }}</button>
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**JS**

```
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
     { name: "item1", price: "1.05" },
     { name: "item2", price: "2.05" },
     { name: "item3", price: "2.55" },
     { name: "item4", price: "2.65" },
     { name: "item5", price: "3.05" },
     { name: "item6", price: "4.95" },
     { name: "item7", price: "4.15" },
     { name: "item8", price: "1.15" },
     { name: "item9", price: "1.95" }
    ];
}
```

Comment: You missed the point, i need to follow the display rule that is max 3 per row. The above just iterates through all the items and will display all 9 in 9 different rows

Answer (score 0):

**A Simplified Example Using CSS**

As I mentioned in my comment above, I believe the best way to achieve your "Grid", is to use CSS. This minimizes coding in your controlers. This leaves your controller more de-coupled from the design. If you want to change the number of items in the grid, you change the CSS, not the template and controller.

An additional advantage is that you can now you CSS Media Queries and change the layout, if required, for mobile devices etc.

My HTML elements of choice for this kind of thing are `ul` and `li`. You may need to add and amend based on your requirements.

**Template**

```
<ul class="buttons">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-primary-items" data-price="1.05">{{ item.name }}</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        name: "item1",
        price: "1.05"
    }, {
        name: "item2",
        price: "2.05"
    }, {
        name: "item3",
        price: "2.55"
    }, {
        name: "item4",
        price: "2.65"
    }, {
        name: "item5",
        price: "3.05"
    }, {
        name: "item6",
        price: "4.95"
    }, {
        name: "item7",
        price: "4.15"
    }, {
        name: "item8",
        price: "1.15"
    }, {
        name: "item9",
        price: "1.95"
    }];
}
```

**CSS**

```
ul.buttons {
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul.buttons li {
    padding: 5px;
    width:30%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gq7Bs/)